# How to create a Restful API with images in ORACLE APEX?

Tags: oracle, image, rest, blob, apex

I need to create a rest method that gets data from a blob column(that i'm using to show images in my application) inside of ORACLE APEX and send that data to another database, Does anybody know what would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Jeff Smith has an article on how to create a REST API that returns images using ORDS: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/11/yet-another-rest-post-and-get-blobs/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.